# Lighttpd Redirect url to Lowercase Version

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, lighttpd

I am using lighttpd, and I would like to redirect uppercase urls to lowercase.

For example, if I have the following url:
http://test.com/info/code/BDAY

I would like to redirect it to:
http://test.com/info/code/bday

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lighttpd's internal mod_rewrite and mod_redirect can only handle pattern matching and substitution, they are unable to do character translation.

You could have a pattern which matches any uppercase character and passes the URL to a script that does the rewrite and returns a redirect

**lighttpd.conf:**

```
url.rewrite-once += ( "(.*[A-Z].*)" => "lower.php?url=$1" )
```

**lower.php:**

```
<?php header("Location: " + strtolower($_GET['url']));
```